# Removing an ancestor during the event bubbling phase

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, dom-manipulation, event-bubbling

In the following code (JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wabdc3Lh/1/)):

```
<form>
   <button>ok</button>
</form>
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(false) ;
    $('button').click(function(){ $('form').remove() }) ;
}) ;
```

When you click the button in Google Chrome 48, it triggers a form submission.
If you do it in Firefox 43, however, there is no form submission.

It seems to me that the Firefox behavior should be the correct one, but since I don't have such a deep knowledge of the standard, I don't really know.

Is either behavior wrong or buggy?

---

**Follow up:**
I just found out that the same test case but without using jQuery doesn't trigger a form submission in neither browser.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <button onclick="form.remove()">ok</button>
</form>
```

This could not be a timing issue because there's no thread concurrency in Javascript. Event threads will always run in sequence, so the `button` event handler must finish before the `form` event handler starts.
I'm blind here. jQuery must be doing some weird cumbersome stuff for this to happen in Chrome.

---

**Follow up 2:**
It's not a jQuery problem. At the jQuery bug tracker I was told that inline event handlers don't follow the same specification as those attached with `addEventListener`, so a true functionally equivalent code should be like this:

```
<form>
    <button>ok</button>
</form>
<script>
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit',function(){ return false }) ;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',function(evt){ evt.target.form.remove() }) ;
</script>
```

And this does behave like the jQuery version.

Comment: @Oriol, the docs say "This method is a shortcut for `.on( "submit", handler )`"

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't find it in the docs, but `on` does `if(fn===false) fn=returnFalse`. I have added an answer.

Comment: @Oriol, the documentation for that is in the description of the `handler` parameter.

Comment: @GetFree Is this on a real site? Are users currently affected by this?

Comment: @oklas, Yes and not anymore. Given this new behavior in Chrome 48 (in which removed forms are submitted anyways), the code was refactored to avoid the problem.

Comment: Chromium code changes [comitted](https://codereview.chromium.org/2261393002). Now behaviour will be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code adds a `returnFalse` jQuery event listener:

```
$('form').submit(false);
```

In a jQuery event listener, `return false` is equivalent to

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

The later should prevent the submission of the form.

However, before the `submit` event is fired, you use `$.fn.remove`. This not only removes the form from the document, it also cleans its jQuery data, including the event listener.

Therefore, when the browser fires the `submit` event to the form, it is not canceled.

Then browsers behave differently ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jL93deuu/)):

- Firefox doesn't submit removed forms
- Chrome doesn't care whether the form has been removed and submits it anyway

If you don't want to remove jQuery data, you should remove the form using vanilla-js methods instead of `$.fn.remove`.

---

In your second code, you cancel the event in a vanilla-js event handler.

Since it's not jQuery data, `$.fn.remove` does not remove it, so the `submit` event is canceled and the form is not submitted.

---

In your third code, you you remove the form using vanilla-js methods, so its jQuery data is not cleaned.

This does not matter because the `submit` event listener is added with vanilla-js too.

However, the event is not canceled. That's because, unlike vanilla-js event handlers and jQuery event listeners, the value returned in a vanilla-js event listener is completely ignored.

So at the end the result is the same than in the first code, but they are not equivalent.

If you want to cancel an event using a vanilla-js event listener, you should use

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This would make it behave like the second code.

Comment: Great answer. The question now is why Chrome is submitting a removed form. This behavior is definitely new in Chrome 48. One of my projects started working wrong because of this right after the update to version 48.

Comment: @GetFree Are you sure? I tried to bisect, but even Chromium 16 sends the form.

Comment: I forgot to mention one little detail. In my project I'm using `<dialog>` elements and not `<form>` elements. The `submit(false)` is so the dialog is not submitted when there is a button click inside the dialog. That mechanism stopped working at some point in January. So I built a minimal test case to reproduce the problem and saw that there were no difference between using a `form` and a `dialog` so I just assumed that whatever made my project stop working affected both.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is implementation dependent and not guarantee identical behaviour

Comment: Is there any source you can refer?

Comment: I think that. I do not find priority reglament about form and it's element submit event called: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission

Comment: and form destroying process may be done immediately or may be deferred and executed after form and its elements handlers called

Comment: The way I understand it, if the form is destroyed after the event bubbles up, the submit event should be canceled by the registered event handler. And if the form is destroyed before the event bubbles up, then there is no form to begin with, so there shouldn't be a submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Both Chromium and Firefox does not call form.onsubmit handler installed by $('form').submit(...) when $('form').remove() called. So this mean that form is checked as destroyed (or realy destroyed) before to call onsubmit in both Chromium and Firefox.

I think that Chromium does not check that form marked as destroyed when process default submit action emitted by button pressing. But Chromium do checking preventDefault flag where default action of button is form submit. So it is possible to add event.preventDefault() before or after $('form').remove().

In opposite Firefox ignore preventDefault of button pressing event and pass control to form.onsubmit.

So behaviour of this two browsers concerning preventDefault and onsubmit is exactly opposite.

As far as fact of form submiting when form is marked as destroyed it is possible to imagine software design where object actually deleted after communication is finished and not before. But seems to me that it is bug. Need to know what developers think. Does they know about it and is this bug or feature.